# SwiftUI always submit fields values as Optional when Rails parses its submitted params

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Especially if you use Ruby on Rails as the backend to handle SwiftUI's request parameters, you may have this issue. So very simple, I'm trying to parse all submitted parameters that is @State in SwiftUI, but when it arrives Rails, they all became Optional....

[image]

And my SwiftUI is very very simple, you can't believe how simple it is, it's just @States and TextFields bind together

```
@State var medicationName = ""
@State var ndc = ""
....and more @States


TextField("Med NAme", text: self.$medicationName)
TextField("Ndc", text: self.$ndc)
```

...and more TextFields and so on...

and WHen they submitted to Rails, they will be like in the image...

personally I don't want to unwrapped them one by one in SwiftUI before submit them and that is so awkward and terrible. Is there any one know if I could make them submitted to Rails as normal values?  Thank you very much!

Here is the Request code, I'm using Alamofire

```
let params: [String : Any] = ["request_token": "...", "medication": [
                            "name": self.medicationName,
                            "date_started": self.dateStartedStr,
                            "strength": self.strength,
                            ]]
                            AF.request("...", method: .post, parameters: params)
```

Comment: Please show the code that makes the server request... there's nothing to indicate in the code that you posted that these values are optional (in fact, they aren't)

Comment: What is `self` in the request code?  How is `medicationName` declared in that object?

Comment: I suspect that somewhere in your code you made the mistake of writing `String(describing: someOptionalString)`, which doesn't unwrap `someOptionalString`, but rather, makes a new string that describes the optional as a whole.